# Erro no envio de array de bytes com Retrofit2

Tags: android, retrofit, okhttp

Estou com o seguinte problema, implementei um solução para envio de imagens com Retrofit2, e meu web service está em um servidor com SSL. O certificado foi implementado recentemente, por isso ele já estava funcionando. Vendo algumas implementações, fiz a seguinte implementação:

```
private void sendImage() {
    OkHttpClient.Builder builder = new OkHttpClient().newBuilder();
    OkHttpClient okHttpClient = builder.build();

    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setLenient().registerTypeAdapter(Usuario.class, new ImageDes()).create();

    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit
            .Builder()
            .baseUrl(context.getResources().getString(R.string.sync_adapter_conn))
            .client(okHttpClient)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
            .build();

    byte[] imageBinary = BinaryBytes.getResourceInBytes(image);
    RequestBody requestBody = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/png"), imageBinary);
    ImageApi imageApi = retrofit.create(ImageApi.class);

    Call<Request> call = imageApi.sendImgRequest(nameImage, requestBody);

    builder.hostnameVerifier(new HostnameVerifier() {
        @Override
        public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session) {

            Certificate[] certs;
            try {
                certs = session.getPeerCertificates();
            } catch (SSLException e) {
                return false;
            }
            X509Certificate x509 = (X509Certificate) certs[0];
            // We can be case-insensitive when comparing the host we used to
            // establish the socket to the hostname in the certificate.
            String hostName = hostname.trim().toLowerCase(Locale.ENGLISH);
            // Verify the first CN provided. Other CNs are ignored. Firefox, wget,
            // curl, and Sun Java work this way.
            String firstCn = getFirstCn(x509);
            if (matches(hostName, firstCn)) {
                return true;
            }
            for (String cn : getDNSSubjectAlts(x509)) {
                if (matches(hostName, cn)) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;

        }
    });

    call.enqueue(new Callback<Request>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<Request> call, Response<Request> response) {
            Log.i("IMAGE_CALL", response.message());
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<Request> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.e("ERRO_CALL", t.getMessage());
        }
    });
}

private String getFirstCn(X509Certificate cert) {
    /*
     * Sebastian Hauer's original StrictSSLProtocolSocketFactory used
     * getName() and had the following comment:
     *
     *      Parses a X.500 distinguished name for the value of the
     *     "Common Name" field.  This is done a bit sloppy right
     *     now and should probably be done a bit more according to
     *     <code>RFC 2253</code>.
     *
     * I've noticed that toString() seems to do a better job than
     * getName() on these X500Principal objects, so I'm hoping that
     * addresses Sebastian's concern.
     *
     * For example, getName() gives me this:
     * 1.2.840.113549.1.9.1=#16166a756c6975736461766965734063756362632e636f6d
     *
     * whereas toString() gives me this:
     * EMAILADDRESS=juliusdavies@cucbc.com
     *
     * Looks like toString() even works with non-ascii domain names!
     * I tested it with "&#x82b1;&#x5b50;.co.jp" and it worked fine.
     */
    String subjectPrincipal = cert.getSubjectX500Principal().toString();
    StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(subjectPrincipal, ",");
    while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {
        String tok = st.nextToken();
        int x = tok.indexOf("CN=");
        if (x >= 0) {
            return tok.substring(x + 3);
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

O erro retornado pelo log, dentro do `call` é a seguinte:

> E/ERRO_CALL: Hostname [IP Servidor] not verified:
>   certificate: [certificado]
>   DN: CN=[url]
>   subjectAltNames: [url, url]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

De acordo com o [issue](https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/1467) que está na documentação do Retrofit, é um erro comum utilizar o IP estático para realizar conexões com WS, só que, pelo que eu entendi o correto mesmo é utilizar o endereço de registro do seu servidor, e realmente, apos eu retirar o endereço de IP o erro não apareceu mais a as imagens foram enviadas normalmente. Vale salientar que isso só ocorre quando se tem conexão com servidores seguros, com certificados com SSL.

No link acima, o @mnasyrov mostra como configurar o seu servidor para aceitar esses tipos de conexão segura. Vale a pena uma lida.